# NSSearchField with left aligned placeholder

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, nssearchfield

After setting `centersPlaceholder = false`, the placeholder aligns correctly at the left, but the search button doesn't show its image. The same is true for the cancel button when entering some text. Is that the correct behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646222/overriding-nssearchfieldcell-causes-placeholder-not-centered) sheds some light on how the strange behavior could be (ab)used to force a left-align in the field. Simply subclass NSSearchFieldCell and override `draw` method:

```
import Cocoa

class FilterFieldCell: NSSearchFieldCell {
    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }
}
```

And then set your search field cell to this class.

Comment: I think you can also fix the drawing by overriding `draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` on a subclass of the `NSSearchField`, and just calling super.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kSearchButtonWidth 22.f

#import "AMSearchField.h"

@implementation AMSearchField

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    // Drawing code here.
}

- (NSRect)rectForSearchButtonWhenCentered:(BOOL)isCentered
{
    CGRect rect = [super rectForSearchButtonWhenCentered:isCentered];
    if (rect.size.width < kSearchButtonWidth) {
        rect.size.width = kSearchButtonWidth;
    }
    return rect;
}

- (NSRect)rectForSearchTextWhenCentered:(BOOL)isCentered
{
    CGRect rect = [super rectForSearchTextWhenCentered:isCentered];
    if (rect.origin.x < kSearchButtonWidth) {
        CGFloat delta = kSearchButtonWidth - rect.origin.x;
        rect.origin.x = kSearchButtonWidth;
        rect.size.width = rect.size.width - delta;
    }
    return rect;
}

@end
```

in xib file, set search class to `AMSearchField`