# Overriding NSSearchFieldCell causes placeholder not centered

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nssearchfield

I'm doing some custom drawing in a `NSSearchFieldCell` subclass. However overriding any of its two drawing methods causes the placeholder text not aligned.

For example, just by using this custom `NSSearchFieldCell` subclass that overrides `NSCell`'s drawing method would cause the placeholder text to be left-aligned.

```
class CustomSearchFieldCell: NSSearchFieldCell {
    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }

    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }
}
```

This is even after setting the search field's `centersPlaceholder` property to `true` and both re-layout the search field or reset the search field's `stringValue`.

Commenting out those two methods would make the placeholder text (and magnifying glass back centered again.

[image: search field center aligned]

However, just one override (even though it does nothing and only calls its superclass' implementation) would make the search field's placeholder text and magnifying glass become left-aligned.

[image: search field left aligned]

The question is, how to get the`center align placeholder` work and still have the custom drawing?

Note that I need to do some custom drawing and mouse handling within the cell, hence the overrides are required.

This was observed on macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: as I looked into my code I have had the same requirement but I didn't used any method to fulfil this thing in my app also I didn't used draw method.

Answer (score -1):

You should look into this method because it gets called when mouse has left the text field and update the frame accordingly :-

```
- (void)stopTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint at:(NSPoint)stopPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView mouseIsUp:(BOOL)flag;
```

I had a requirement to vertically centre the text of NSSearchFieldCell and below code did the trick so you can give it a try to centre the components you want - :

```
//
//  VerticallyCenteredTextFieldCell.m
//
//  Created by Vikram on 01/03/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Vikram. All rights reserved.
//

#import "VerticallyCenteredTextFieldCell.h"

@implementation VerticallyCenteredTextFieldCell

- (NSRect)adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:(NSRect)frame
{
    // super would normally draw text at the top of the cell
    NSInteger offset = floor((NSHeight(frame) -
                              ([[self font] ascender] - [[self font] descender])) / 2);
    return NSInsetRect(frame, 0.0, offset-3);
}
- (void)editWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView
               editor:(NSText *)editor delegate:(id)delegate event:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super editWithFrame:[self adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:aRect]
                  inView:controlView editor:editor delegate:delegate event:event];
}
- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView
                 editor:(NSText *)editor delegate:(id)delegate
                  start:(NSInteger)start length:(NSInteger)length
{

    [super selectWithFrame:[self adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:aRect]
                    inView:controlView editor:editor delegate:delegate
                     start:start length:length];
}
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)view
{
     [super drawInteriorWithFrame:
     [self adjustedFrameToVerticallyCenterText:frame] inView:view];
}

@end
```

I have made it in objective-c so read it accordingly and make it useful in swift.

Comment: Is this from [RSVerticallyCenteredTextFieldCell](https://red-sweater.com/blog/148/what-a-difference-a-cell-makes) ?